# Is there any way to set a System::Windows::Forms::Form derived GUI's thread name?

Tags: .net, multithreading, debugging, c++-cli

I have a `System::Windows::Forms::Form` derived GUI whih is part of a fairly heavily threaded application. The app is launched with a call to `Application::Run`.

To aid debugging, I'd like to name each thread so it's clearer in my profiler which is currently the bottleneck. I've been able to do so for others that are derived from `Threading::Thread` using their `Thread::Name` property.

Is there any way to do this for my GUI thread?

Comment: Erm, it already has a name.  "Main Thread", good name.

Comment: I had assumed (wrongly it would seem) that the call to `Application::Run` was launching the GUI in a new thread..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also use `Thread::Name` property but in the proper place. In C# I'd do it in the following way. I'm not sure but in C++/CLI it should be the same.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...

    Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Main UI Thread";

    Application.Run(new MainApplicationForm());  
}
```

**Edit (by JC)** - This is the call in C++-cli:

```
Threading::Thread::CurrentThread->Name = "My Thread Name";
```

Comment: Perfect - nailed it :-)